# Basic problem React with express dynamic table

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am creating my first crud application with react and express, but I can not create a dynamic table that I am receiving from a sql cosulta.

The error is: props.datos.map is not a function.

I do not know if I'm doing it correctly or maybe I'm using bad practices.

I was seeing and it may be because the call is asynchronous and due to this.

I must change the state of the component and not deliver the data for props.

Express js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'shells'
});
connection.connect(); 


// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

// create a GET route
app.get('/express', (req, res) => {
  // res.send({ saludo: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT' });
  connection.query('select * from shell', function(err, rows, fields) {

    res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
  });




});
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import SideBar from './sideBar'
import Table from './table'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SideBar> 
        <Table datos={rows}/> 
      </SideBar> 



    );
  }
}

export default App;

var rows= fetch('/express')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    return response;
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });

  console.debug(rows)
  console.log(rows)
```

Table.js

```
function SimpleTable(props) {


  return (
    <Paper className={props.root}>
      <Table className={props.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Familia</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Genero</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Especie </TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Calidad </TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Tamaño </TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Pais </TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Comentario </TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Precio </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {props.datos.map(molusco => {
            return (
              <TableRow >
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {molusco.familia}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{molusco.genero}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{molusco.especie}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{molusco.calidad}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{molusco.tamaño}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{molusco.pais}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{molusco.comentario}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{molusco.precio}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}

SimpleTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTable);
```

Comment: Are you importing `import React from 'react'` in `Table.js`?

Comment: Yes i do it. This is not a problem. Thanks for you answer

Comment: if `props.datos.map` is not a function, the most likely scenario is that what you're feeding to `Table` in the `rows` variable is not an Array (and therefore it doesn't have the map function in its prototype). Try logging `rows` to see if you're actually passing in an array.

Comment: I made a console.log to print the rows variable but it does not print anything, I do not know what I will be doing wrong or if row does not have anything. I did it in the following way console.log ({rows}). I think that you say is correct. rows is not array, because it arrives empty (i think)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because `rows` variable is not an array. It's a promise.
You should assign it another way:

```
let rows = [];

const loadingPromise = fetch('/express')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
     rows = json
  })
```

And a better way to manage async data is to use lifecycle methods of React.Component. By doing that you can guarantee that `rows` variable will be defined in `render` method, and Component will be auto rerender when you will get a response from the server.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rows: []
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(users => {
        this.setState({rows: users});
      })
  }
  
  render () {
    const {rows} = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        {rows.length === 0 && "Loading..."}
        
        <ul>
          {rows.map((row, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{row.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This work for me. Thanks a lot! I could not understand why it did not work, it made my life haha

Comment: The `fetch` function returns a Promise which is not actual data you're trying to get. To read more about promises you can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Just change the 'rows' variable a bit and it is a good practice to put the async requests within the Component Lifecycle Methods. I think it will work.

```
fetch('/express')
  .then(function(response) {
   response.josn()
})
.then(function(myJson) {
  rows=[...myJson];
});
```

Comment: This not work for me, but in the first answers its work. Thanks! :)